# AWS Lambda NewRelic Integration with Typescript and webpack

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda function developed using Typescript and I'm using webpack to build the lambda.
Here is the AWS SAM template for lambda.

```
MyAppTokenValidator:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Join [ "-", [ "my-app-token-validator", !Ref Environment ] ]
      Handler: token-validator.handler
      CodeUri: src/api/
      Policies:
        - AmazonSSMFullAccess
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const AwsSamPlugin = require('aws-sam-webpack-plugin');

const awsSamPlugin = new AwsSamPlugin();

module.exports = {
    entry: () => awsSamPlugin.entry(),
    output: {
        filename: (chunkData) => awsSamPlugin.filename(chunkData),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        path: path.resolve('.')
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        alias: {
            '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
        }
    },
    target: 'node',
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
    },
    plugins: [awsSamPlugin]
};
```

My `npm run build` command will simply execute `webpack-cli` and this setup is working perfectly fine.

Then I try to integrate new relic to instrument `MyAppTokenValidator` lambda. I update the SAM template as below.

```
MyAppTokenValidator:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Join [ "-", [ "my-app-token-validator", !Ref Environment ] ]
      Handler: newrelic-lambda-wrapper.handler <<<--- use newrelic lambda wrapper
      CodeUri: src/api/
      Policies:
        - AmazonSSMFullAccess
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NEW_RELIC_LAMBDA_HANDLER: token-validator.handler <<<--- here is the my handler
          NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID: <ACC_ID>
          NEW_RELIC_TRUSTED_ACCOUNT_KEY: <ACC_KEY>
          NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY: <KEY>
          NEW_RELIC_LAMBDA_EXTENSION_ENABLED: true
          NEW_RELIC_EXTENSION_SEND_FUNCTION_LOGS: true
          NEW_RELIC_DISTRIBUTED_TRACING_ENABLED: true
```

When I try to execute `npm run build` command now I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR in MyAppTokenValidator
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/api//newrelic-lambda-wrapper' in ''
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

The NR wrapper isn't located inside `src/api/`.  The Lambda runtime is set up with a search path that looks first in `/var/task` (where your `src/api` is located) and then in `/opt/nodejs` (where our wrapper is, in `node_modules/newrelic-handler-wrapper` ).

Typescript doesn't run in Lambda; it's typically built and transpiled into common JS in a `dist` directory within `var/task`.

I'd suggest to remove `CodeUri` from their template, and use the `NEW_RELIC_LAMBDA_HANDLER` value to point to the transpiled `token-validator.handler` that's probably in `dist`. (It might be in `dist/api` ; they should have a sense of where their code gets built.)